# How can I save data inside a variable that is defined outside of a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, promise, callback

I am trying to save in a variable the data received from a request to a mongoDb database with this code:

```
var riskRatingTable = [];
RiskRating.find((err, tableData) => {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else
    riskRatingTable = tableData;
});
//This returns undefined
console.log('riskRatingTable: ', riskRatingTable);
```

After having made some research, I have found that this solvable by using callback or promises:
[Solving js asynchronous functions problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)
So I tried this:

```
 var riskRatingTable = [];
    RiskRating.find((err, tableData) => {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
        else
        riskRatingTable = tableData;
    }).then((tableData)=>{
        riskRatingTable = tableData;
s    });
    console.log('riskRatingTable: ', riskRatingTable);
```

But, I get this error:

> (node:2916) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: s is not
>   defined

Any idea how I can fix this?
Thank you !!

Comment: You didn't read the duplicate closely enough. You cannot access the value generated by the callback function before the callback function has run.

Comment: I understand that. But, what's the solution??

Comment: To use the value inside the callback.

Comment: Should I pas the riskRatingTable variable as an argument to the callback function?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You aren't calling the callback function, so you can't … and since you are defining the callback function in the scope that contains `riskRatingTable` … it already has access to it.

Comment: Alright, do you advise me to use promises then?

Comment: You're already using promises.